# UNIX - unable to print more than 1 variable in a command

Tags: linux, unix

I am facing a weird situation in UNIX.

I have 2 variables - var1 and var2

When I try to print the values:
echo $var1$var2

It only print $var2 value. Similarly, if I do this with 3 variables, only the last variable's value gets printed...

Please help as to what the issue is and how it can resolved.

EDIT1: identified the issue - it was due to end-of-line characters

The following answer gave me the answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45772568/8336579

Comment: Did you leave a space between the two vars?

Comment: Yes Space, no space - same result

Comment: But I found the issue - it was actually what value was there inside these 2 variables - the variable were reading value from a file - and that file had windows end-of-line characters (\r\n) - and then that value was passed to awk command - which was just interpreting the \n, thus leaving \r in the end - which was causing the cursor to return to the starting of line.

The following answer proved super helpful:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45772568/8336579

Comment: Ah, yes, the dreaded linefeed character